# How to get the current date and time

Tags: java, datetime

How do I get the current date and time in Java?

I am looking for something that is equivalent to `DateTime.Now` from C#.

Comment: This Question is older than [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5175728/642706) formerly marked as a duplicate. So I reversed the designation, reopening this Question and marking the newer one as the duplicate.

Comment: @BasilBourque only problem is that the most recent question also has a better answer meaning it is more up to date. Most of the methods of `Date` which is here suggested as the accepted answer are deprecated as of 2022 making it mostly useless IMO.

Comment: To anyone who stumbles across this question - please be aware that most of the answers on this page are obsolete, and you shouldn't use them.  The only really good answer here is that of @BasilBourque, so you could either read that answer, or visit the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5175728) which Basil has also answered.

Comment: @ArturoMendes Yes, you are correct. I regret my actions then in reversing the duplicate designation. At the time I thought the rule was that older Questions should prevail. Since then I learned on the Meta pages that the rule is that quality of the Question, and the quality of its Answers, should prevail rather than age.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

Just construct a new `Date` object without any arguments; this will assign the current date and time to the new object.

```
import java.util.Date;

Date d = new Date();
```

In the words of [the Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Date.html) for [the zero-argument constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()):

> Allocates a Date object and **initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated**, measured to the nearest millisecond.

Make sure you're using `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date` -- the latter doesn't have a zero-arg constructor, and has somewhat different semantics that are the topic of an entirely different conversation. :)

Comment: Also note that GregorianCalendar and many similar objects work the same way.  So whatever type of date/calendar object you are working with, the zero-argument constructor usually initializes the object to the current date/time.

Comment: From Date doc: As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be used to convert between dates and time fields and the DateFormat class should be used to format and parse date strings.

Comment: Please consider new Java8 APIs - [LocalDateTime.now() and ZonedDateTime.now()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26225884/513342)

Answer (score 58):

The Java [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) classes are considered by many to be poorly designed.  You should take a look at [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), a library commonly used in lieu of Java's built-in date libraries.

The equivalent of `DateTime.Now` in Joda Time is:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

**Update**

As noted in the comments, the latest versions of Joda Time have a `DateTime.now()` method, so:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
```

Comment: The current(2.1) version of Joda seems to have a static DateTime.now method()  (optionally accepts DateTimeZone or Chronology). http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#now%28%29

Comment: Note that this answer was posted in 2010. Java 8 has absorbed many of Joda Time's best features. See the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) and many other online articles for more information.

Answer (score 56):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
```

## java.time

The java.util.Date class has been outmoded by the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)) in Java 8 and later. The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Get the current moment in java.time.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

A [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) encapsulates:

- Date.
- Time-of-day, with a fraction of a second to [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution.
- Time zone.

If no time zone is specified, your JVM’s current default time zone is assigned silently. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone than rely implicitly on default.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

## UTC

Generally better to get in the habit of doing your back-end work (business logic, database, storage, data exchange) all in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone. The code above relies implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

The `Instant` class represents a moment in the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

The `Instant` class is a basic building-block class in java.time and may be used often in your code.

When you need more flexibility in formatting, transform into an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Specify a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) object. For UTC use the handy [constant for UTC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

## Time Zone

You easily adjust to another time zone for presentation to the user. Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), *never* the 3-4 letter codes such as `EST` or `IST`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime nowMontreal = instant.atZone( z );
```

Generate a String representation of that date-time value, localized.

```
String output = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )
    .format ( nowMontreal );
```

## `Instant`

Or, to stay in UTC, use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). An `Instant` object represents a moment on the timeline, to nanosecond resolution, always in UTC. This provides the building block for a zoned date-time, along with a time zone assignment. You can think of it conceptually this way:

> [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) = [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) + [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)

You can extract an `Instant` from a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instantNow = zdt.toInstant();
```

You can start with an Instant. No need to specify a time zone here, as `Instant` is always in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Comment: I also posted [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39379431/642706) with more details on a duplicate Question.

Answer (score 16):

I prefer using the Calendar object.

```
Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
```

I find it much easier to work with.  You can also get a Date object from the Calendar.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: Or it can be simply `Calendar.getInstance()`

Answer (score 14):

In Java 8 it's:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 12):

```
import java.util.Date;   
Date now = new Date();
```

Note that the [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object is mutable and if you want to do anything sophisticated, use [jodatime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 10):

`java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();` will return the datetime since the epoch

Comment: Good for logging but requires parsing and conversion for displaying to user

Answer (score 6):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you create a new Date object, by default it will be set to the current time:

```
import java.util.Date;
Date now = new Date();
```

Answer (score 3):

Java has always got inadequate support for the date and time use cases. For example, the existing classes (such as `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormatter`) aren’t thread-safe which can lead to concurrency issues. Also there are certain flaws in API. For example, years in `java.util.Date` start at 1900, months start at 1, and days start at 0—not very intuitive. These issues led to popularity of third-party date and time libraries, such as `Joda-Time`. To address a new date and time API is designed for Java SE 8.

```
LocalDateTime timePoint = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(timePoint);
```

As per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--):

> **The method `now()` returns the current date-time using the system
>   clock and default time-zone, not null**. It obtains the current
>   date-time from the system clock in the default time-zone. This will
>   query the system clock in the default time-zone to obtain the current
>   date-time. Using this method will prevent the ability to use an
>   alternate clock for testing because the clock is hard-coded.