# How to get today's Date?

Tags: java, date

In other words, I want functionality that provides Joda-Time:

```
today = today.withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

but without Joda-Time, only with java.util.Date.

Methods such as .setHours() and etc. are deprecated. Is there are more correct way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010284/equivalent-of-datetime-now-in-java

Comment: By the way, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 added a method to set the time to first moment of the day: [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()). It smartly finds the first moment for a given time zone, which is not always `00:00:00` because of Daylight Saving Time or other anomalies. That method supplants the no-longer-recommended "midnight" classes and methods.

Comment: More popular dup of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850874/how-to-create-a-java-date-object-of-midnight-today-and-midnight-tomorrow

Comment: While when this question was asked in 2011 it was reasonable to use `java.util.Date` in spite of its design issues, today that class has been completely supplanted by [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). So don’t use `Date` anymore. And never again. See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33225963/5772882).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
Date today = new Date();
today.setHours(0); //same for minutes and seconds
```

Since the methods are deprecated, you can do this with `Calendar`:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // same for minutes and seconds
```

And if you need a `Date` object in the end, simply call `today.getTime()`

Comment: @Plastic Rabbit your timezones are not fine then. Use `Calendar.getInstance(utcTimezone)` for example.

Comment: Wouldn't `today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)` be better? `clear` sets the field to *undefined*, while `set` sets it to a defined value.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 14):

```
Date today = DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

[DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) from Apache Commons-Lang. Watch out for time zone!

Comment: Throws exception 'The field 6 is not supported ...' :(

Comment: I'm sorry, it should have been `DAY_OF_MONTH`, rather than `DAY_OF_YEAR`, answer corrected.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there are more correct way?

Yes, there is.

```
LocalDate.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
).atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
)
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later now has the new java.time framework built-in. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310, and extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project.

### Examples

Some examples follow, using java.time. Note how they specify a time zone. If omitted, your JVM’s current default time zone. That default can vary, even changing at any moment during runtime, so I suggest you specify a time zone explicitly rather than rely implicitly on the default.

Here is an example of date-only, without time-of-day nor time zone.

```
ZoneId zonedId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zonedId );
System.out.println( "today : " + today );
```

> today : 2015-10-19

Here is an example of getting current date-time.

```
ZoneId zonedId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zonedId );
System.out.println( "zdt : " + zdt );
```

When run:

> zdt : 2015-10-19T18:07:02.910-04:00[America/Montreal]

### First Moment Of The Day

The Question asks for the date-time where the time is set to zero. This assumes the first moment of the day is always the time `00:00:00.0` but that is not always the case. Daylight Saving Time (DST) and perhaps other anomalies mean the day may begin at a different time such as `01:00.0`.

Fortunately, java.time has a facility to determine the first moment of a day appropriate to a particular time zone, [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-). Let's see some code using the `LocalDate` named `today` and the `ZoneId` named `zoneId` from code above.

```
ZonedDateTime todayStart = today.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

> zdt : 2015-10-19T00:00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

## Interoperability

If you must have a java.util.Date for use with classes not yet updated to work with the java.time types, convert. Call the [`java.util.Date.from( Instant instant )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 12):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/)

Answer (score 6):

If you want midnight (0:00am) for the current date, you can just use the default constructor and zero out the time portions:

```
Date today = new Date();
today.setHours(0); today.setMinutes(0); today.setSeconds(0);
```

**edit**: update with `Calendar` since those methods are deprecated

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.clear(Calendar.HOUR); today.clear(Calendar.MINUTE); today.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
Date todayDate = today.getTime();
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code ;

```
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

This will shown as :

Feb 5, 2013 12:39:02PM

Comment: Question was not about a `String`.

Comment: @JonasByström Check question's subject. Whenever any user face same problem, question's subject appear in Google search links from Stack Overflow. My answer fulfill question's subject.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to easy get Date & Time :

```
package date.time;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;    
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat dnt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy :: HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Today Date & Time at Now :"+dnt.format(date));  
    } 
}
```

Comment: This Answer does not address the Question. The Question wants the time-of-day set to zero, midnight. Also, this Answer uses terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Suggesting their use in 2018 is poor advice. And a third problem, this Answer ignores the crucial issue of time zones.

Answer (score 0):

**Code To Get Today's date in any specific Format**

You can define the desired format in SimpleDateFormat instance to get the date in that specific formate

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        String todaysdate = dateFormat.format(date);
         System.out.println("Today's date : " + todaysdate);
```

Follow below links to see the valid date format combination.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

**CODE : To get x days ahead or Previous from Today's date, To get the past date or Future date.**

For Example :

Today date : 11/27/2018

xdayFromTodaysDate = 2 to get date as 11/29/2018

xdayFromTodaysDate = -2 to get date as 11/25/2018

```
  public String getAniversaryDate(int xdayFromTodaysDate ){

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,xdayFromTodaysDate);
        date = cal.getTime();
        String aniversaryDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        LOGGER.info("Today's date : " + todaysdate);
          return aniversaryDate;

    }
```

**CODE : To get x days ahead or Previous from a Given date**

```
  public String getAniversaryDate(String givendate, int xdayFromTodaysDate ){


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        try {
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(givendate);
            cal.setTime(date);
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,xdayFromTodaysDate);
            date = cal.getTime();
            String aniversaryDate = dateFormat.format(date);
            LOGGER.info("aniversaryDate : " + aniversaryDate);
            return aniversaryDate;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: These terrible classes were outmoded years ago with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), implemented in the modern [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Suggesting the use of these legacy classes in 2018 is poor advice.