# How to create a Java Date object of midnight today and midnight tomorrow?

Tags: java, date

In my code I need to find all my things that happened today. So I need to compare against dates from today at 00:00 AM (midnight early this morning) to 12:00 PM (midnight tonight).

I know ...

```
Date today = new Date();
```

... gets me right now.  And ...

```
Date beginning = new Date(0);
```

... gets me zero time on Jan 1, 1970.  But what's an easy way to get zero time today and zero time tomorrow?

---

### UPDATE

I did this, but surely there's an easier way?

```
Calendar calStart = new GregorianCalendar();
calStart.setTime(new Date());
calStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calStart.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calStart.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date midnightYesterday = calStart.getTime();
            
Calendar calEnd = new GregorianCalendar();
calEnd.setTime(new Date());
calEnd.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)+1);
calEnd.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calEnd.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calEnd.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calEnd.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date midnightTonight = calEnd.getTime();
```

Comment: In my opinion Joda Time is easier, look at the end of my answer. If you want to use java.util.Date/Calendar you have to do this way, there is no easier way to do it.

Comment: RE: timaschew comment to use Joda-Time, know that the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, and advises migration to the java.time classes.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: It’s seldom to see so many flawed answers to a question as to this one. I recommend [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784346/5772882), it is correct and knowledgeable.

Comment: try to concat `hh:mm aa` as `11:59 pm` to `SimpleDateFormat` object

Answer (score 412, accepted):

## java.util.Calendar

```
// today    
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
// reset hour, minutes, seconds and millis
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// next day
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

---

## JDK 8 - java.time.LocalTime and java.time.LocalDate

```
LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
LocalDateTime todayMidnight = LocalDateTime.of(today, midnight);
LocalDateTime tomorrowMidnight = todayMidnight.plusDays(1);
```

---

## Joda-Time

If you're using a JDK < 8, I recommend [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), because the API is really nice:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime().toDateMidnight().toDateTime();
DateTime tomorrow = date.plusDays(1);
```

Since version 2.3 of Joda Time `DateMidnight` is **deprecated**, so use this:

```
DateTime today = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime tomorrow = today.plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Pass a time zone if you don't want the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Montreal");
DateTime today = new DateTime(timeZone).withTimeAtStartOfDay(); // Pass time zone to constructor.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had just updated my original question with how I was currently doing it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As of JodaTime 2.3, `toDateMidnight` is deprecated. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19048833/363573

Comment: added a solution for JDK 8

Comment: Your top example doesn't work for me. It gives "12:03:00" for time instead of "00:00:00". Basic Java calendar sure does suck.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? For me it's working fine with JDK8 and it should also work in 6.

Comment: @timaschew While generally correct, I suggest doing the java.time using a zoned date-time value (`ZonedDateTime`) as you did in the Joda-Time section. The `Local…` types have no time zone information – that is their entire purpose, no lose/ignore all offset and time zone details. Especially as the Question talks about using these values for comparison (maybe database queries?), a zoned date-time value is likely to be more useful.

Comment: @timaschew for a Java Calendar object you recommend setting up using new GregorianCalendar().  Others recommend using Calendar.getInstance();  Is there an advantage to your method?

Comment: @Amalgovinus Make sure to set Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, not Calendar.HOUR.

Answer (score 81):

For sake of completeness, if you are using **Java 8** you can also use the `truncatedTo` method of the `Instant` class to get midnight in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

As written in the Javadoc

> For example, truncating with the MINUTES unit will round down to the nearest minute, setting the seconds and nanoseconds to zero.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Getting the midnight at specified timezone becomes lengthier: `Date.from(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toInstant())`

Comment: Beware of [difference between `truncatedTo` and `atStartOfDay`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143910/java-8-date-time-get-start-of-day-from-zoneddatetime).

Answer (score 39):

The easiest way to find a midnight:

```
Long time = new Date().getTime();
Date date = new Date(time - time % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Next day:

```
Date date = new Date(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I ran that code and got: Midnight: Thu Nov 01 19:00:00 CDT 2012

Comment: If you did something like System.out.print(date), the system converted the date instance into the system time zone (CDT). 7pm in CDT is midnight in GMT. If you need a midnight in a selected time zone, you have to add this time zone's offset, taking DST into account.

Comment: @Bouncner  It is. There are many different 'midnight' times on Earth regardless of which method you use, but there is only one Java midnight.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin Did not know that there is a "java midnight". ;)
What I wanted to say it that this solution does imo not really help the topic creator. A calendar solution avoids ugly second-calculations and takes care of timezones (and especially day light savings times etc.) when used properly. I don't see that in your solution.

Comment: Hi @AndreiVolgin , I got with Date date = new Date(time+ TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() - time % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

Answer (score 33):

Remember, `Date` is not used to represent *dates* (!). To represent date you need a calendar. This:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
```

will create a `Calendar` instance representing present date in your current time zone. Now what you need is to truncate every field below day (hour, minute, second and millisecond) by setting it to `0`. You now have a midnight today.

Now to get midnight next day, you need to add one day:

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Note that adding `86400` seconds or 24 hours is incorrect due to summer time that might occur in the meantime.

UPDATE: However my favourite way to deal with this problem is to use [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) class from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang):

```
Date start = DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
Date end = DateUtils.addDays(start, 1);
```

It uses `Calendar` behind the scenes...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  "Date is not used to represent dates" -- we'll that's pretty freakin brilliant, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @RobertHume To be fair, Date has been around since the first release of Java. Most things from that era are... less than perfectly thought out. Especially since Java was among the first to try the sorts of things it was trying, and there was _far_ from an agreed-upon standard for how to do it.

Answer (score 17):

these methods will help you-

```
public static Date getStartOfDay(Date date) {
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTime(date);
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
     return calendar.getTime();
 }
```

and

```
public static Date getEndOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Other answers are correct, especially the [java.time answer by arganzheng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31919380/642706). As some mentioned, you should avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes as they are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. They have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

Let me add notes about strategy around **handling midnight** and **spans of time**.

## Half-Open

In date-time work, spans of time are often defined using the “Half-Open” approach. In this approach the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This solves problems and if used consistently makes reasoning about your date-time handling much easier.

One problem solved is defining the end of the day. Is the last moment of the day `23:59:59.999` ([milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond))? Perhaps, in the java.util.Date class (from earliest Java; troublesome – avoid this class!) and in the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. But in other software, such as database like Postgres, the last moment will be `23:59:59.999999` ([microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)). But in other software such as the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework (built into Java 8 and later, successor to Joda-Time) and in some database such the [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/), the last moment might be `23:59.59.999999999` ([nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)). Rather than splitting hairs, think in terms of first moment only, not last moment.

In Half-Open, a day runs from the first moment of one day and goes up to but *does not include* the first moment of the following day. So rather than think like this:

> …from today at 00:00am (midnight early this morning) to 12:00pm (midnight tonight).

…think like this…

> from first moment of today running up to but not including first moment of tomorrow:
> ( >= `00:00:00.0` today AND < `00:00:00.0` tomorrow )

In database work, this approach means *not* using the [`BETWEEN` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Operators) in SQL.

## Start of day

Furthermore, the first moment of the day is *not* always the time-of-day `00:00:00.0`. [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) in some time zones, and possibly other anomalies, can mean a different time starts the day.

So let the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes do the work of determining the start of a day with a call to [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay( ZoneId )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-). So we have to detour through [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and back to [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) as you can see in this example code.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
ZonedDateTime todayStart = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( zoneId );
ZonedDateTime tomorrowStart = todayStart.plusDays( 1 );
```

Note the passing of the optional `ZoneId`. If omitted your JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit.

Time zone is crucial to date-time work. The Question and some other Answers are potentially flawed because the do not consciously handle time zone.

## Convert

If you *must* use a java.util.Date or .Calendar, look for new conversion methods added to those old classes.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( todayStart.toInstant() );
java.util.GregorianCalendar gregCal = java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( todayStart );
```

## Span of time

By the way, if you are doing much work with spans of time take a look at:

- [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)
- [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)
- [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html)
  The `Interval` class is found in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, an extension to the java.time framework. This project is the proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.
  `Interval todayMontreal = Interval.of( todayStart.toInstant() , tomorrowStart.toInstant() );`

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 10):

JDK8 - Java Time Module way:

`LocalDateTime todayMidnight = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();`

Also work:

`LocalDateTime todayMidnight = LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);`

Comment: It’s usually better to use `ZonedDateTime` than `LocalDateTime`. And in any case I suggest specifying time zone, even if it is just `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. In any case thanks for mentioning java.time, the modern Java date and time API, it’s the good choice for the job.

Answer (score 9):

As of JodaTime 2.3, the `toDateMidnight()` is deprecated.

From [Upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/upgradeto230.html)

```
    Deprecations since 2.2
    ----------------------
    - DateMidnight [#41]
     This class is flawed in concept
     The time of midnight occasionally does not occur in some time-zones
     This is a result of a daylight savings time from 00:00 to 01:00
     DateMidnight is essentially a DateTime with a time locked to midnight
     Such a concept is more generally a poor one to use, given LocalDate
     Replace DateMidnight with LocalDate
     Or replace it with DateTime, perhaps using the withTimeAtStartOfDay() method
```

Here is a sample code without `toDateMidnight()` method.

**Code**

```
DateTime todayAtMidnight = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
System.out.println(todayAtMidnight.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

**Output** (*may be different depending on your local time zone*)

```
2013-09-28 00:00:00
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I would make the addition of passing an [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) instance to that [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor to stress the importance of specifying a time zone rather than inadvertently depending on the default: `DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );`

Answer (score 7):

## java.time

If you are using Java 8 and later, you can try the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)):

```
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
Date endDate = Date.from(tomorrow.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: Good answer. I would suggest specifying the desired/expected time zone. The JVM’s current default time zone can vary by OS settings, changing computers, or any app in any thread of the JVM changing the default at any moment during runtime.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be an option:

```
DateFormat justDay = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date thisMorningMidnight = justDay.parse(justDay.format(new Date()));
```

to add a day to it, either

```
Date tomorrow = new Date(thisMorningMidnight.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

or

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(thisMorningMidnight);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date tomorrowFromCalendar = c.getTime();
```

I have a hunch the latter is preferred in case of something weird like daylight savings causing adding 24 hours to not be enough (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336131/32453 and its other answers).

Comment: I have a date and time of day represented as a long in my sqlite database.  I need to get a long for the beginning of the next day.  Can I still use a Date object with my long rather than with the SimpleDateFormat method that you use above?

Comment: As long as it's the right milliseconds you can pass it as a constructor: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)

Answer (score 2):

Using apache commons..

```
//For midnight today 
Date today = new Date(); 
DateUtils.truncate(today, Calendar.DATE);

//For midnight tomorrow   
Date tomorrow = DateUtils.addDays(today, 1); 
DateUtils.truncate(tomorrow, Calendar.DATE);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque Agreed for Java 8. But if OP is using Java 7,  I guess still that would work.

Comment: Nearly all of the *java.time* functionality is available for Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project with virtually identical API. Further adapted for Android <26 in the *ThreeTenABP* project. So no need to ever again use those wretched old date-time classes.

Answer (score 1):

I did this differently than everyone else here did.  I'm new to Java, so maybe my solution is poor.

```
Date now = new Date();
Date midnightToday = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
```

I'm not sure this works yet, but either way, I'd appreciate any feedback on this solution.

I'm confused by the statement above that you can calculate tomorrow by calling:

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

If you add 1 to the day of the month and it's the 31st day, don't you get the 32nd day of the month?

Why are times/dates not all based on UTC in Java?  I would think Timezones should only be needed when used with i/o, but internally should always be used in UTC.  However, the classes seem to include Timezone info which seems not only wasteful, but prone to coding errors.

Comment: Hi Mitch.  I think your solution works, but it looks like that Date constructor is deprecated.  The Java folks deprecated most of the original Date related methods a while back and replaced them with newer Calendar related methods.  Personally I don't see how it's an improvement, but it's frowned on to use deprecated methods.  Thanks!

Comment: Sad about the deprecation.  It seems much cleaner to me to specify the year, month and date rather than clearing the hour, minute, second and millisecs.  Clearing these relies on millisecs being the finest granularity of the Date class, while my solution doesn't.  My solution is also shorter and clearer.  Being new to Java makes me really appreciate just how clean, easy and efficient C++ is when it comes to using dates and times.

Comment: @Mitch In my experience, the most recent language you're learning is always perceived as the most complicated.

Comment: FYI: these bloody awful old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much as the answers before, but nobody mentioned AM_PM parameter:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
```

Comment: The troublesome `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Lang

```
DateUtils.isSameDay(date1, date2)
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#isSameDay(java.util.Date, java.util.Date)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way with JodaTime

`DateMidnight date = DateMidnight.now();`

Comment: No. The "midnight"-related classes and methods in Joda-Time have all been deprecated. They were based on a flawed concept. The first moment of the day is not always `00:00:00.000`. Instead use the new [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method. Update to the current version 2.4 of Joda-Time and read the release notes. Example: `DateTime today = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();`

Answer (score 0):

Because of one day is `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` ms, 
the midnight of this day can be calculate as...

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long delta = now % 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
long midnight = now - delta;
Date midnightDate = new Date(midnight);`
```

Comment: This code only applies to UTC and no other time zone, and ignores anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time. Furthermore, roll-your-own date-time solutions is unwise as this is a surprisingly tricky topic. Use the excellent java.time classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date now= new Date();
// Today midnight
Date todayMidnight = new Date(endTime.getTime() -endTime.getTime()%DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY);

// tomorrow midnight
Date tomorrowMidnight = new Date(endTime.getTime() -endTime.getTime()%DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY + DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY);
```

Comment: This only works for UTC, and fails to address time zones. Also, the terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by `java.time.Instant`. Avoid using `Date` nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very old post. I thought to share my knowledge here !

For the date Mid night today with exact Time zone you can use following

```
public static Date getCurrentDateWithMidnightTS(){

    return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (System.currentTimeMillis()%(1000*60*60*24)) - (1000*60 * 330));
}
```

Where   `(1000*60 * 330)` is being subtracted i.e. actually related to time zone for example Indian time zone i.e. kolkata differs +5:30hrs from actual . So subtracting  that with converting into milliseconds.

So change last substracted number according  to you. I m creating a product i.e. only based in India So just used specific timestamp.

Comment: Why would you suggest this instead of the accepted answer? Rolling your date-time values is risky in general. In particular this code is hard-coded to a single time zone's current offset forever. There is no accounting for Daylight Saving Time or other anomalies. I see only downsides with no added value.

Comment: @Basil  of course  I accept answer and yes I mentioned there for hard coded value . This is helpful only in case of you are working on a  specific time zone .

Answer (score -1):

```
Date todayMidnightUTC = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
Date tomorrowMidnightUTC = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1));
Date anyMidnightLocal = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.from(dateTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

But beware that `java.sql.Date.toInstant()` always throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Via [LocalDate to java.util.Date and vice versa simpliest conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simpliest-conversion/33066935#33066935)

Comment: *Not* a good Answer. You are mixing the use of the modern java.time with the old legacy classes they supplant. And specifically you use the java.sql date-time classes that should only be used for exchanging data with a database whose driver has not yet been updated to deal directly with the java.time classes, never to be used for business logic. Yet another problem is that you ignore the crucial issue of time zone.

Comment: @BasilBourque, thanks for the critique. Using one legacy class that isn't marked as deprecated to obtain another legacy class instance is quite safe. The timezone issue is more important. I decided to stick with riccardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467674/603516) after all.

Answer (score -1):

Old fashioned way..

```
private static Date getDateWithMidnight(){
    long dateInMillis = new Date().getTime();
    return new Date(dateInMillis - dateInMillis%(1000*60*60*24) - TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(dateInMillis));
}
```

Comment: That troublesome class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time.Instant* class. No need to ever use `Date`.

Comment: That `Date` class is always in UTC. So you are ignoring the issue of the desired/expected time zone. For example, a new day dawns in Kolkata India many hours earlier than in UTC, and hours later than UTC in Montréal Québec.