# how to get the beginning of a day using Gregorian Calendar and Date in java

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

i am trying to mark date if the data created in the past 3 days. I want to take the last 3 days , from the beginning (00:00).

i have this code :

```
    int days = 3 
    GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -days);
    if (timeCreated.before(gc.getTime())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

if the current time is 16:00 clock i get the past 3 days , from 16:00 clock to now.
I want to get from 00:00 3 days ago till now.

Comment: Set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to zero on your calendar. An example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850874/how-to-create-a-java-date-object-of-midnight-today-and-midnight-tomorrow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set the hours, minutes and seconds in your calendar object to zero.

```
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 0);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, 0);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```

Remember to do this AFTER you have called `gc.add`.

Comment: i was updating as you commented.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE,0);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND,0);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```