# Compare two timestamp days

Tags: java, javascript, couchdb

In my application I designed a Spring scheduler that should pick records that has "abcDate" field with tomorrow's timestamp as value.

I have calculated timestamp in my java application as,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            long abcTimeStamp = DateUtils.convertDateTimeToUTCzone(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

value of this is : 1387348986 i.e) 12 / 18 / 13 @ 6:43:06am UTC

In DB I have a record, with timestamp 1387365854 i.e) 12 / 18 / 13 @ 11:24:14am UTC.

I am using couch DB map reduce view, and I pass the timestamp value as key to the view.

But since the time is different in both timestamps, I am not able to fetch this record. Is there a way to match only the days in timestamp and filter the records in view itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB's concept of `startkey` and `endkey` is super useful here.

It sounds like you've already got a view, but just for the sake of completeness let's assume it looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/mydesign",
   "_rev": "1-088646f81629ce559b6d9772c6116113",
   "views": {
       "by_timestamp": {
           "map": "function(doc) { emit(doc.timestamp, doc); }"
       }
   }
}
```

And you've got a database named 'timestamps' running locally with a handful of documents, as shown by:

```
$ curl localhost:5984/timestamps/_design/mydesign/_view/by_timestamp
```

To get a range of documents, add the `startkey` and `endkey` query parameters:

```
$ curl localhost:5984/timestamps/_design/mydesign/_view/by_timestamp\?startkey\=1387348986\&endkey\=1387365854
```

Now to get those parameters you'll need the timestamp of the start of tomorrow and the end of tomorrow. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850919/460826) covers that with the `java.util.Calendar` API and Joda-Time.

For more on finding many, check out CouchDB's awesome [new docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.5.x/couchapp/views/intro.html#find-many).

Answer (score 0):

Check [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It is a javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Comment: I have to use couch db map reduce view js to compare them. So I cannot use this library.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Joda time API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It has more features.

From a calendar you can get the Date with the method getTime(). This date you can use for an object from the above API. Or use milli secs:

```
...
DateTime dt = new DateTime(millis);
int day = dt.getDayOfYear();
...
```