# Finding every first Sunday of the month between 1900 and a user-input year

Tags: java, date

This is homework.

I am trying to find every occurrence of a Sunday landing on the first of a month between Jan 1 1900 (which we are assuming was a Monday) and Dec 31 of a year that the user inputs. The calendar extension is off-limits.

I am returning dates in the correct format, but they do not match up with the example code our instructor provided.
In the given example, an input of 1902 should return:
1 Apr 1900
1 Jul 1900
1 Sep 1901
1 Dec 1901
1 Jun 1902

For 1902, my code returns:
1 Mar 1900
1 Jan 1901
1 Apr 1901
1 May 1901
1 Feb 1902
1 Jun 1902
1 Jul 1902

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sundays {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the ending year: ");
    int userInputYear = reader.nextInt();

    int[] orderedLengthOfMonthsArray = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    String[] orderedNamesOfMonthsArray = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    int month = 0;
    int dayOfWeek = 1; // initialized to MONDAY Jan 1, 1900 -- Sunday would be #7
    int dayOfMonth = 1;


    for (int year = 1900; year <= userInputYear; year++) {

        for (month = 0; month < orderedLengthOfMonthsArray.length; month++) {


            for (dayOfMonth = 1; dayOfMonth <= orderedLengthOfMonthsArray[month]; dayOfMonth++) {

                dayOfWeek++;

                if (dayOfMonth == 1 && dayOfWeek == 7) {
                    System.out.println(dayOfMonth + " " + orderedNamesOfMonthsArray[month] + " " + year);
                }

                if (dayOfWeek == 8) {
                    dayOfWeek = 1;
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: You're also neglecting leap years.

Comment: I should have mentioned that we are assuming no leap years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the if statement and the increase of `dayOfWeek`.

```
        for (dayOfMonth = 1; dayOfMonth <= orderedLengthOfMonthsArray[month]; dayOfMonth++) {
            if (dayOfMonth == 1 && dayOfWeek == 7) {
                System.out.println(dayOfMonth + " " + orderedNamesOfMonthsArray[month] + " " + year);
            }

            dayOfWeek++;

            if (dayOfWeek == 8) {
                dayOfWeek = 1;
            }                   
        }
```

When you are in the dayOfMonth `for` loop, you already have the correct day of the week (initially Monday, Jan 1st, 1900), so if you first increase it, then the check afterwards would be incorrect.

Comment: Interesting — this solved it. Thank you for the helpful explanation as well. Order really is everything!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dayOfWeek == 7) {
    dayOfWeek = 1;
}
```

So your week has 6 days? I think you should either reset to zero  or reset when `dayOfWeek` is 8.

Answer (score 1):

Someone mentioned [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) magic… So here's my solution using Joda-Time 2.3.

While the question (a homework assignment) forbade the use of added libraries…

- The comparison may be enlightening.
- The student should soon learn that the java.util.Date & Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided for real-world work. They are supplanted in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) by the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) which is inspired by Joda-Time and defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

My example code uses [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) which should only be used if your are **absolutely certain** that you don't care about (a) time of day, and (b) time zones. I do not usually recommend this approach as naïve programmers who believe they need neither time nor zone often turn out to be mistaken.

```java
// Start
LocalDate start = new LocalDate( 1900, 1, 1 );

// Stop
// Using "half-open" comparison. We care about December 31 of specified year, but we will test for January 1 of year after.
String input = "1930";
int year = Integer.valueOf( input );
year = ( year + 1 );  // Add one to get to next year, for "half-open" approach.
LocalDate stop = new LocalDate( year, 1, 1 );

// Collect each LocalDate where the first of the month is a Sunday.
java.util.List<LocalDate> localDates = new java.util.ArrayList<LocalDate>();
LocalDate localDate = start;
do {
    if ( localDate.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY ) { // Comparing 'int' primitive values.
        localDates.add( localDate ); // Collect this LocalDate instance.
    }
    localDate = localDate.plusMonths( 1 ); // Move on to next month. Joda-Time is smart about various month-ends and leap-year.
} while ( localDate.isBefore( stop ) ); // "Half-Open" means test "<" rather than "<=".
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "The First-Of-The-Month days that are Sundays from " + start + " (inclusive) to " + stop + " (exclusive):" );
System.out.println( localDates );
```

```
The First-Of-The-Month days that are Sundays from 1900-01-01 (inclusive) to 1931-01-01 (exclusive):
[1900-04-01, 1900-07-01, 1901-09-01, 1901-12-01, 1902-06-01, 1903-02-01, 1903-03-01, 1903-11-01, 1904-05-01, 1905-01-01, 1905-10-01, 1906-04-01, 1906-07-01, 1907-09-01, 1907-12-01, 1908-03-01, 1908-11-01, 1909-08-01, 1910-05-01, 1911-01-01, 1911-10-01, 1912-09-01, 1912-12-01, 1913-06-01, 1914-02-01, 1914-03-01, 1914-11-01, 1915-08-01, 1916-10-01, 1917-04-01, 1917-07-01, 1918-09-01, 1918-12-01, 1919-06-01, 1920-02-01, 1920-08-01, 1921-05-01, 1922-01-01, 1922-10-01, 1923-04-01, 1923-07-01, 1924-06-01, 1925-02-01, 1925-03-01, 1925-11-01, 1926-08-01, 1927-05-01, 1928-01-01, 1928-04-01, 1928-07-01, 1929-09-01, 1929-12-01, 1930-06-01]
```

Comment: Nice. Don't forget that you can format the output with `localDate.toString("dd MMM yyyy");` as for timezones, I would use [DateMidnight](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) or even [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) + `withTimeAtStartOfDay`. Joda is so cool that you can change the type  and it will work.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Valid points, except that `DateMidnight`. The "midnight" classes and methods are no longer recommended by the Joda-Time team. That [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method was added in v2.3 to supplant the midnight-stuff. See [this answer by Alex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19048833/642706) for doc.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, while you have explicitly mentioned not to use `Calendar`, here is how we could do it:

```
public static List<Date> mondaysFirst(int firstYear, int lastYear) {
    final List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    c1.set(firstYear, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    final Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    c2.set(lastYear, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59);

    while (c1.before(c2)) {
        final int dayOfTheWeek = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // is sunday
        if (dayOfTheWeek == 1) {
            dates.add(c1.getTime());    
        }
        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }

    return dates;
}
```

And to print the results:

```
final List<Date> dates = mondaysFirst(1900, 1902);
final SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
for (Date date: dates) {
    System.out.println(sf.format(date));
}
```

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/W21TRq).

---

I'm sure that there is some [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) magic to make this even shorter.