# Counting sundays appears in first day of month

Tags: java, date

I wrote this code above to get number of sundays appears in first day of the month. I don't get a correct result and dont have idea why? any suggestion?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

    public class Test{
          public static void main(String args[]) {
            int counter = 0;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            for (int i = 1900; i<=2000; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j <=11; j++){
                    c.set(i, j, 1);
                    int day_of_week = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    if(day_of_week==1){
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
          }   
    }
```

Comment: What result do you get? And what is the correct result?

Comment: Over 101 years, there have been 173 months where the first day of the month has been on a Sunday (is the result I'm getting from the above question)

Comment: For starters, change `day_of_week==1` to `day_of_week==Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK.SUNDAY` . It may be clear to you that 1 represents Sunday, but it is not immediately clear to everyone reading your code. If you use the enumerated type, you are clearly referring to Sunday.

Comment: Why `day_of_week==1`? Where did you get that 1 is Sunday? You should always use the constant `Calendar.SUNDAY`.

Comment: Something to keep in mind (if this is coming from [Project Euler #19](http://projecteuler.net/problem=19)), the 20th century does not include 1900. Is the correct answer 171?

Comment: What result do you expect to get?

Comment: @m0skit0 The Javadoc has a list of the values for the various enumerated types inside of Calendar. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY

Comment: Correct answer is 171. And i forgot about one thing. The 1900.1.1 day is a Monday, the calandar.day_of_week for that date return 5, so i assume that sunday is a 4 and i paste wrong code  if(day_of_week==1) here should be ==4. But it doesnt matter because the result still is not correct.

Comment: java.util.Calendar: public static final int SUNDAY = 1

Comment: Somebody else had [nearly the same homework assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21896589/642706). Most importantly, you'll learn to avoid using java.util.Date & .Calendar for serious work. Instead use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (or java.time in Java 8) as shown in [my answer to that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901080/642706).

Answer (score 4):

The 20th century includes years from 1901 to 2000. By amending your for-loop...

```
for (int i = 1901; i <= 2000; i++){
```

You will get 171 months.

---

In addition, using hard-coded values in code is generally a bad thing; look at some of [PearsonArtPhoto's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075861/642706)

Comment: OMG it was so stupid :) thank you very much. It is 20th century so my code was correct. Big thanks again :)

Comment: No problem! Is this for Project Euler?

Comment: ChrisForrence, Yes it is :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there's several things to make the code clearer that could be done. But I suspect the crux of the question is that you should start from the year 1901, as that's technically the first day of the century. As far as code clean up, here's a few tips:

1. Use variable names that mean something, like year and month.
2. Use constants, instead of just enumerating the value (`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK.SUNDAY`)

Put everything together, and you've got:

```
public class Test{
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        int counter = 0;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int Day_Of_Month=1; //This makes it easier in case you want to tweak the test, to say, 

        for (int year = 1901; year<=2000; year++){
            for (int month = 0; month <12; month++){
                c.set(year, month, 1);
                int day_of_week = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                if(day_of_week==Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK.SUNDAY){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
      }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tips and sorry for unclear code but i'm begginer in programing and still learning.

Comment: No problem, I'm just trying to help you learn for the future, that's all;-)