# When I enter an old date (e.g., 20/03/1961 (dd/mm/yyyy) the value one day earlier is stored

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, gwt

I am using MySQL, Eclipse, GWT java and when I enter  an old date 20/03/1961 (dd/mm/yyyy) the value stored is 19/03/1961. I get the same result irrespective of whether I manually input the date or use the date picker (i.e., it displays as 20/03/1961 on input but when I redisplay it displays as 19/03/1961). I have checked the DB (MySQL) and it is stored as 1961-03-19. In the DB the column is defined as date and collation is utf8_general_ci.

The error seems to only occur between certain date ranges. On the 12/12/2014 @ 11:24 I tested by halving dates back and I found the error on 4/4/1971, i.e., 5/4/1971 was stored correctly and 4/4/1971 was stored as 3/4/1971. I then entered the original date I had trouble with, 31/3/2004 and the error occurred (i.e., it was stored as 30/3/2004). I have been trying various other dates and found 3/4/2007 is stored as 2/4/2007 while 4/4/2007 is OK. a mathematical genius could probably find a pattern to this.

The relevant code is:

Client side:

```
final DateBox dateBoxDOB = new DateBox();

//dateBoxDOB = new DateBox();
dateBoxDOB.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")));
flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, dateBoxDOB);
dateBoxDOB.getDatePicker();

java.sql.Date sqlDOB = new java.sql.Date(dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime());

AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new UpdateHandler<Void>(EditYouthMemberView.this);
                rpc.updateYouthMember(cd_ID, textBoxSurname.getText(), textBoxFirstName.getText(), sqlDOB, 
                    imagePath, sqlDateArchived, integerBoxScoutNumber.getValue(), sd_ID, "Cubs",
                    "Explorer", sqlPackIn, sqlDatePackOut, callback);
```

Server side:

```
public void updateYouthMember(String cd_id, String surname,
    String firstname, java.sql.Date dob, String photograph, java.sql.Date archived,
    Integer scout_no, String sd_id, String section, String pack, java.sql.Date startDate,
    java.sql.Date endDate) {

PreparedStatement ps = null;
PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
// Create connection/statement variables outside of try block
Connection c = null;

String updateWithoutPhoto = ("UPDATE at_cub_details " +
        "SET cd_surname = ?, " +
        "cd_first_name = ?, " +
        "cd_dob = ?, " +
        "cd_archived = ?, " +
        "cd_scout_no = ? " +
        "WHERE cd_id = ?;");

String updateWithPhoto = ("UPDATE at_cub_details " +
        "SET cd_surname = ?, " +
        "cd_first_name = ?, " +
        "cd_dob = ?, " +
        "cd_photograph = ?, " +
        "cd_archived = ?, " +
        "cd_scout_no = ? " +
        "WHERE cd_id = ?;");

try {
    // Get Connection and Statement from DataSource
    c = ds.getConnection();

    try {
        if (photograph == null) {
            // Create a statement and execute the query on it
            ps = c.prepareStatement(updateWithoutPhoto);
            ps.setString(1, surname);
            ps.setString(2, firstname);
            ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) dob);
            ps.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) archived);
            ps.setInt(5, scout_no);
            ps.setString(6, cd_id);

            ps.executeUpdate();

            // Clean up
            ps.close();
        }else{
            // Create a statement and execute the query on it
            ps = c.prepareStatement(updateWithPhoto);
            ps.setString(1, surname);
            ps.setString(2, firstname);
            ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) dob);

            File imgfile = new File (photograph);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imgfile);
            ps.setBinaryStream(4, fis, (int) imgfile.length());

            ps.setDate(5, (java.sql.Date) archived);
            ps.setInt(6, scout_no);
            ps.setString(7, cd_id);

            ps.executeUpdate();

            // Clean up
            ps.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println("SQLException in updateYouthMember: " + se.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Errors occurred in updateYouthMember: " + e.toString());
    }

String updateSectionDetails = ("UPDATE at_section_details " +
        "SET sd_section = ?, " +
        "sd_pack = ?, " +
        "sd_start_date = ?, " +
        "sd_end_date = ? " +
        "WHERE sd_id = ?;");
try {
    // Create a statement and execute the query on it
    ps2 = c.prepareStatement(updateSectionDetails);
    ps2.setString(1, section);
    ps2.setString(2, pack);
    ps2.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) startDate);
    ps2.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) endDate);
    ps2.setString(5, sd_id);

    ps2.executeUpdate();

    // Clean up
    ps2.close();
    c.close();

} catch (SQLException se) {
    System.out.println("SQLException in updateYouthMember - updateSectionDetails: " + se.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Errors occurred in updateYouthMember - updateSectionDetails: " + e.toString());
}

} catch (SQLException e1) {
    System.out.println("SQLException in updateYouthMember: " + e1.toString());
    e1.printStackTrace();

} 

finally {

// Ensure connection is closed and returned to the pool, even if errors occur.
// This is *very* important if using a connection pool, because after all the
// connections are used, the application will hang on getConnection(), waiting
// for a connection to become available.
// Any errors from the following closes are just ignored.  The main thing is
// that we have definitely closed the connection.
try { if(ps != null) ps.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
try { if(c != null) c.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
}
// Done
}
```

I have already tried:

I found this: bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71084. However, when I use ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) dob, java.util.Calendar.getInstance()); I still get 19/03/1961 when I enter 20/03/1961.

I tried:

```
// create a calendar Locale locale1 = Locale.UK; 
TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+10:00"); 
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(tz1, locale1); 
ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) dob, cal1);
```

and this did not work.

I also tried `TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("AEST");` which did not work either.

I then tried `ps.setString(3, dob.toString());` which causes a `Errors occurred in updateYouthMember: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the timezone set to on your server(s)? Have you tried using UTC?

Comment: It would really help if you post only the relevant code.

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch, the host has the server set to “Australia/Melbourne” (we are in the same time zone although I am in Sydney). Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a time zone issue. Here are a few pointers:

1. If you are storing the date as a String, you may want to process it as a String in GWT as well. It will save you from trouble when converting from Long to a date.
2. If you prefer to use `getTime()` to get the date, try to adjust this number to a midnight (see my answer to this question: [how to create a Java Date object of midnight today and midnight tomorrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850874/how-to-create-a-java-date-object-of-midnight-today-and-midnight-tomorrow/12319431#12319431))

GWT returns a point of time that is noon instead of midnight. It may enough to push the date one day back for some combination of dates and time zones.

This may not be enough, though - you may need to adjust the `getTime()` result by a time zone offset before converting it into a Date object, and then use the same offset the other way when showing the date in your app - the same date starts at a different time in different time zones.

3. Alternatively, you can use `getTime()` to get time in milliseconds, store it as time in milliseconds, and then use it as time in milliseconds as well when displaying the date. This works for things like timestamps and the like, where the time zone is irrelevant. If time zone is important, you will have to remember in which time zone to display the date - it may be the correct date in some time zones and 1 day off in the other.

I would recommend the latter two approaches only if you need exact time adjusted for a user's time zone somewhere in your app. If you only need dates, strings is a simpler solution.

Comment: Hi Andrei,I am trying your suggestion by changing java.sql.Date sqlDOB = new java.sql.Date(dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime()); to Long time = new dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime(); and get an error that dateBoxDOB can not be resolved to a type. Thanks for your help, Glyn

Comment: @Glyn `new dateBoxDOB`? Remove `new`. `dateBoxDOB` is a variable, not a type. The error message was telling you exactly what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch. That was correct; However, unfortunately, it did not resolve my issue. I still get the wrong date stored for some dates. Oh, and the date is being stored as a date in the DB. Regards, Glyn

Comment: @Glyn debug your code. Something has an incorrect timezone set somewhere that you haven't shown us.

Comment: This means that you convert your Long into a date before you store it. Store it as a Long. If you want to store a date, as I mentioned in my response, you have to adjust the time in milliseconds you get from the DateBox by your time zone's offset. Midnight in Australia is still a previous day in Greenwich.

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch, I have searched for the setting of a timezone and can not find one. I added some displays. I entered 31/03/2004


Window.alert("Date Box = " + dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime()); is 1080651600000

Window.alert("date = " + date); just before the rpc call is 2004-03-30

So the wrong date is being passed from the client.
Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi @AndreiVolgin, I added the code you suggested Long time = dateBoxDOB.getValue().getTime();
     Date date = new Date(time - time % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); and I still get the same result. Regards, Glyn

Comment: *So the wrong date is being passed from the client.* Fix the **client**.

Comment: "I still get the same result." Of course you do: you don't adjust the time by your time zone offset. 1080651600000  converts to 13:00 on March 30, 2004 in GMT, which is a midnight of March 31, 2004 in Australia eastern time zone during the daylight saving time (add 11 hours). As I said, you either get Long - store Long - retrieve Long - create date on the client using the same Long, or you have to make adjustments using the time zone offset. Or simply use Strings throughout.

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch and Andrei, Thank you for all your help and persisting with me. I have gained respect for java programmers from this little project of mine for the Scouts. From your what I have found the how "String dobString = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dateBoxDOB.getValue());". Thank you very much. Regards, Glyn