# How do I only save date and not datetime in google datasource

Tags: android, google-app-engine, datetime

I'm working on an android app with gae as backend. I have two queries around DateTime object `com.google.gdata.data.DateTime`

1. While inserting data, I only want to to insert date and not datetime. Here's current object creation and it saves both date and time.

   ```
   stock.setDate(new DateTime(new Date()));
   ```
2. Also while retrieving stock object, where I have aggregated data, I want to group by date and not datetime. But as the data got stored as date and time, I'm getting group by datetime, where as I want date. What to do in such scenarios (yes, if we solve 1st problem this wont be required, but otherwise what should be done). My retrieval code is

   ```
   List<AggregatedStock> execute = null;

   PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
   Query query = pm
           .newQuery(" select date, vehicleCode, vehicleSubCode, colorCode, sum(count) from Stock as AggregatedStock ");

   query.setFilter(" updatedByDealer == " + dealer);
   query.setGrouping(" date, vehicleCode, vehicleSubCode, colorCode ");
   query.setOrdering(" vehicleCode desc ");

   query.declareImports("import com.sandeepapplabs.dms.Stock");

   try {
       List<Object[]> results = (List<Object[]>) query.execute();

       execute = new ArrayList<AggregatedStock>();

       for (Object[] result : results) {
           execute.add(new AggregatedStock((Date) result[0],
                   (String) result[1], (String) result[2],
                   (String) result[3], ((Long) result[4]).intValue()));
       }

   } finally {
       pm.close();
   }

   return execute;
   ```

Comment: Some people downvote without thinking. Don't be upset. And welcome to the community!

Comment: And sometimes a question is down-voted when it's author could not be bothered to search for the hundreds of pre-existing duplicate Qiestions and Answers.

Comment: @BasilBourque: In which case it is useful (and polite) to explain to a *new* member why a question was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` is a single moment in time. It's a not a "day" that lasts 24 hours. When you call `new Date()`, you get a different moment - down to a millisecond - each time. Note that there is no difference here between Date and DateTime - the [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is simply a Date with a chronology.

You have three options if you want to use the "date as a day" to group your entities:

(a) Always set the date as a midnight ([how to create a Java Date object of midnight today and midnight tomorrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850874/how-to-create-a-java-date-object-of-midnight-today-and-midnight-tomorrow/12319431#12319431)).

(b) Save it as `new Date()`, but extract the "day" portion or convert it into a String formatted to represent a calendar day before using it to group entities.

(c) Store and use dates as String values (i.e. "2014-12-24").

Answer (score 0):

App Engine supports `java.util.Date` as a property. Complete list of supported value types can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types)

Comment: Yes it does, but when I generate cloud endpoint libraries, it creates model classes with Date as DateTime. Sample from generated model

    `@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public final class Stock extends         com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {

  /**
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private com.google.api.client.util.DateTime date;`

Comment: Any why a downvote?? I'm new to this so please let me know so that I improve things at my end