# Calendar <= another calendar

Tags: java, calendar

```
while (r.next()) {
    String rn = r.getString(3);
    String sqldate = r.getString(2); // database reservation date
}
```

Getting date from database

```
DateFormat RD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     java.sql.Date converteddate = new java.sql.Date(RD.parse(sqldate).getTime());
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTime(converteddate);
     cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
     if(cal<=cal1){ }// i need to this opration i dont know how
```

I need to check `cal` is <= `Cal1`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the simple method:

```
if (cal.before(cal1)) { ... }
```

This reads: "If a date is before another date, you should do the following..".

I think it makes it easier to read if you write "before" than "compareTo", even though the operation is the same. [Also read the documentation for Java Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29).

EDIT:
I've updated the answer a bit to include what's been commented below so the answer is more complete. Thanks to assylias for pointing it out, but if you want to compare if a date is before or equal to another date, you should use:

```
if (!cal.after(cal1)) { ... }
```

This reads: "If a date is not after another date, you should do the following..". Also note that "not after" is the same as "before or equal to".

Comment: Note that before is equivalent to `cal.compareTo(cal1) < 0`, not `cal.compareTo(cal1) <= 0`, which would be equivalent to  `!cal.after(cal1)`.

Comment: @assylias Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer to include that point, so it's a more complete answer.

Comment: how to check today is btween cal1 cal2 ?

Comment: `if (today.after(cal1) && today.before(cal2)) { ... } ` if you want to know if today is between cal1 and cal2.

Answer (score 9):

Calendar being Comparable, you can use the [`Calendar#compareTo()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29):

> `compareTo` returns the value 0 if the time represented by the argument is equal to the time represented by this Calendar; a value less than 0 if the time of this Calendar is before the time represented by the argument; and a value greater than 0 if the time of this Calendar is after the time represented by the argument

In your case, to determine if `cal` is before or equal to `cal1`, you would use:

```
if (cal.compareTo(cal1) <= 0) {}
```

Comment: can you please explain me what 0 do?

Comment: Have you clicked on the link I have provided? *"compareTo returns the value 0 if the time represented by the argument is equal to the time represented by this Calendar; a value less than 0 if the time of this Calendar is before the time represented by the argument; and a value greater than 0 if the time of this Calendar is after the time represented by the argument."*

Comment: thank you i have one more problem, how to check today is btween cal1 cal2 ?

Comment: Get [today's date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046771/how-to-get-todays-date) in calToday and check that cal1 <= calToday and calToday <= cal2.