# Calendar today between two calendars?

Tags: java, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calendar <= another calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950279/calendar-another-calendar)

```
Calendar newdate = Calendar.getInstance(); // Collect before this date 
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
rdate.setTime(converteddate);
newdate.setTime(converteddate);
newdate.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
```

How to check today is between `rdate` and `newdate`?

Comment: Use `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date` unless you are using JDBC.

Comment: This question appears to be the same as your previous one. Voted to close as *exact duplicate*.

Comment: Just a tip for you!

If you can use external libraries, joda time is a good tool for calculating dates etc.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

```
rdate.after(today)&&rdate.before(newdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 (today.after(rdate) && today.before(newdate) ||
 (today.after(newdate) && today.before(rdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if ( today.after( rdate ) && today.before( newdate ) ) { .... }
```

assuming that `newdate` is always later than `rdate`, which your code comments suggest.

Cheers,