# Recalculation of datetime in Java Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, time

What's the best way determining the datetime inside a Java Thread (in Android)?

I have the following snippet:

```
public void repeatedlyPrintTheTime() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    mR = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Time 1 is " + mCalendar.getTime().toString());
            System.out.println("Time 2 is " + GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(mR, 1000);
}
```

Time 1 repeatedly prints the same time, but Time 2 updates on every iteration.

Do I really have to get a new instance of GregorianCalendar every time I want to check what the time is?

Comment: What is your requirement? `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()` creates a `Calender` with current time and timezone. `mCalender` is already initialized and not initializing every time, so it is printing its time (either set or created time)

Comment: That or LocalDateTime.now() (Java8 only) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java for detailed analysis.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard this is Android, therefore no Java 8... Heck, Android doesn't even have Java 7

Comment: Note that you could use a `ScheduledExecutorService`

Comment: why not use `new java.util.Date()` or just `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: So GregorianCalendar.getInstance() doesn't provide an object which can *tell* the time (at any future point), but rather provides an object which can provide information about the time that it was instantiated? OK, got it, thank you (if you want to provide that as an answer I'll happily accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Yes, you must get a fresh date-time object instance each time you want to capture the current moment. No automatic updating of existing instance.

```
Instant.now()
```

## Single moment, not updated automatically

A `GregorianCalendar` holds a single moment, and is *not* automatically updated. If it were updating automatically, you would never be able to do any business logic as the value would constantly be changing as your code ran!

## Using java.time

Also, `GregorianCalendar` and its sibling classes are an awful mess and should be avoided. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Use `Instant` for the current moment in UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-02-27T14:48:58.664Z

To later capture the current time again, obtain another `Instant` instance.

```
Instant instantLater = Instant.now();
```

> instantLater.toString(): 2017-02-27T14:49:02.164Z

You can even capture the delta between them, as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( instant, instantLater );
```

> duration.toString(): PT3.5S

To see that same moment through the lens of some particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), adjust into a time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-02-27T09:48:58.664-05:00[America/Montreal]

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/kyoE1t).

To represent a moment in the future or the past, specify inputs to get an `OffsetDateTime` or a `ZonedDateTime`.

> JavaDoc…
>
> ZonedDateTime.of( int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond, ZoneId zone )

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34 , 56 , 123456789 , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some calendar classes are not thread-safe. You could insert that code in a `synchronized` block with a lock:

```
private Object calendarLock; --Class attribute

public void repeatedlyPrintTheTime() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    mR = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(calendarLock) {
                System.out.println("Time 1 is " + mCalendar.getTime().toString());
                System.out.println("Time 2 is " + GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(mR, 1000);
}
```