# Getting a date in java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I've just started to learn java and can't fully understand every step of getting a date (e.g. `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);` . Can someone please explain it to me? Sorry if the question is stupid

Comment: Are you trying to get the current date/time?

Comment: Read about Date API in Java....also, remember to read about Joda time, currently quite popular.....usually people using java.util.Date.....`Date date = new Date()`;

Comment: Oracle provide excellent online tutorials for most aspects of Java programming.  Start there.

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java and lots of tutorial related to this

Comment: If you use Java 8 you should probably use the new java time api instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/index.html

Comment: @ Jamie Reid just trying to entirely understand every step.

Everyone else, thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can get the current date time via following two classes – Date and Calendar. And, later use SimpleDateFormat class to convert the date into a user friendly format.

Using Date() + SimpleDateFormat():

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2014/08/06 15:59:48
```

Using Calender() + SimpleDateFormat()

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); //2014/08/06 16:00:22
```

Here's a full example to show you how to use Date() and Calender() classes to get and display the current date time.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

       //get current date time with Calendar()
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

  }
}
```

Please review the following two manual pages:

- [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
- [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score -1):

Full examples provided in the links below:

1)[examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/)

2)[gete date and Calendar](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mkyong.com%2Fjava%2Fjava-date-and-calendar-examples%2F&ei=RAvyVJaqJ9PWasvRgXg&usg=AFQjCNH2dTGDE9YUd3Gh13Q_6_FirdfD3g&bvm=bv.87269000,d.d2s&cad=rja)

The java.util.Calendar.getInstance() method gets a calendar using the specified time zone and specified locale.The point of using getInstance() is that it will take the default locale and time-zone into account when deciding which Calendar implementation to return and how to initialize it.

Comment: its better to add code snippet in answer itself rather than providing links

Comment: @Raunak Kathuria In this case man the link have obviously examples with explaining.If it is more information needed by the asker i will provide them.

Comment: I have not downvoted relax. just saying so that next person who comes can get an overview of your answer and if more details required he can open link