# How to Make/Set a time limit by date for my java program

Tags: java, demo

I am working with java application programs,especially billing software.

I want to gave my application program as demo version for customers.
So I want to set my program for a limited period of time(30 days Trial),
and after that It should ask for a valid key for continuing.

How is it possible to Set a 30 days time period for my application in Java.

Any Idea is acceptable

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If everyone choose Google,Then whats the use of                                        STACK OVERFLOOOOOOO

Comment: It's for after you've actually made an effort to research and attempt the problem yourself first.

Comment: As a counter point to @tnw's view, most of the top google results are stack overflow - and most of them have similar complaints of "google it first next time".

Comment: Ehm... what? The question I linked has none of that and 10 different answers to choose from.

Comment: Actually StackOverflow.com was [founded with the intention](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html) of being amongst the top hits in a Google search. Showing effort is not the issue, rather the question must be specific, "Every question in Stack Overflow is like the Wikipedia article for some extremely narrow, specific programming question. How do I enlarge a fizzbar without overwriting the user’s snibbit? This question should only appear once in the site. Duplicates should be cleaned up quickly and redirected to the original question."

Comment: @Basil "Actually StackOverflow.com was founded with the intention of being amongst the top hits in a Google search." That's what stackoverflow need....But we thought that, some good people were here for understanding the problems of unskilled people and trying to sort it out.And it was our mistake.

Comment: And if something like that, tell me a website for helping students like me.I don't want this account..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see the linked article about how to get and manipulate the date. This will be very useful in the future.

[How to get the current date/time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java)

Second, you will only have to do some simple comparisons to clarify what the current date is, versus the fixed limit for the license. Depending on how you are distributing this, you will want to implement the licenses in different ways. For instance, include a fixed start date (such as the day you distribute) and have the expiration be one month later. Your other option is to dynamically update a license key that specifies the current date, every day. This way when you send it out later you will be covered from the day you sent it out - as opposed to from a fixed date.

Comment: Thanks for this Idea

Comment: I only wants to know How the developers make trial software..You told me that to set a date for its initial use,and check for the destination day,Right bro

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TrueLicense](http://truelicense.java.net), because just verification of the trial time and license key sometimes is not enough and it raises a few more complicated problems.

Comment: Oh god..Thanks for this Link,,I want to create something by myself.Is there any different Idea frnd..