# Setting timestamp to current time in Java

Tags: java, derby

I'm trying to set the current datetime in a java EE7 web app to an apache derby database I have.

I'm using timestamp in both java and derby so I don't have to worry about type conversions.

However, the only way I know of to get the current datetime is through calendar.set(Calendar time).

Is there inherent way to set the current datetime for timestamp or will I need to use a converter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java

Comment: In SQL, there is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsqlj15866.html#rrefsqlj15866

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Date class for initializing to the current time , i.e :

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

The java.util.Calendar class is an abstract encapsulation of the Date object.
Calendar provides getter and setter for the date fields , nothing more. And it comes at a cost.

In your case using a simple Date is ideal.

Comment: You are welcome! Remember not to use Calendar unless you absolutely need it. It comes with some overhead.

Answer (score 1):

use joda jar and import the required packages.

```
DateTime d = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(TIME_ZONE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code.

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```