# How DO I convert ZoneId to DateTimeZone in Java

Tags: datetime, java-8, jodatime

How to convert the ZoneId to DateTimeZone?
I have :

```
 Private Instant logTime;  //java.time
    Private ZoneId timeZoneId;   //java.time
```

But I need to get DateTime and DateTimeZone (both org.joda.time) from the above. I got DateTime from Instant like =

```
Private DateTime  dateTime ;   //org.joda.time
private DateTimeZone dateTimeZone;   //org.joda.time

LocalDateTime currentTime = new LocalDateTime(logTime);
dateTime = currentTime.toDateTime();
```

For dateTimeZone, I did  :

```
dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId.getId()); // getting java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But getting error. Can someone tell mw how to do it properly

This gives me error. Can some one tell how should I convert this. I need to get the current time for the given zoneId.

Comment: A `ZoneId` doesn't have any date/time information. Did you mean get the current time in a specific zone id?

Comment: So I can get the current time (localTimezone) in a specific zone id ?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post with what you have and what you want then? Because it is unclear at the moment.

Comment: Are you trying to use `java.time` or jodatime or mix the two?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33100195/1743880

Comment: There is no `ZoneId` class in jodatime.  that's a class from `java.time`.  Mixing the two APIs is going to cause a lot of confusion because many classes are named the same.  For example, it's not clear if `private Instant logTime` is a `java.time.Instant` or `org.joda.time.Instant`

Comment: @Misha Updated the question

Comment: Update your question with the error that you are getting.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] for guidelines.

Comment: @Learner Your question is not making sense. The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later is the official successor to the Joda-Time library. There should be no need to mix the two.

Comment: Thanks for now pointing out the NPE but you have still not given any information/data why your variable `timeZoneId` is null. Please check how you create this variable. Do you set it at all?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same time zone conversion issue and I could achieve the conversion by completing @basil-bourque answer on this post [Converting from java.util.TimeZone to org.joda.DateTimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266220/converting-from-java-util-timezone-to-org-joda-datetimezone) with a call to `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone#forTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone zone)` .

```
final java.time.ZoneId timeZoneId;
final org.joda.time.DateTimeZone timeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId))
```