# How to store date and current time in database from HTML?

Tags: java, html, sql, timestamp

I am developing a simple web project. I want to store the date selected by the user with current time in the MySQL database. While trying to do that I am getting time as 00:00:00. What should I do to get the current time?

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
String startdate = req.getParameter("date1");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(startdate);
Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
emp.store(timestamp); //method to store in database
```

In HTML page:

```
<input type="datetime" name="date1"/>
```

Comment: You're using a date-only format mask when you're parsing the incoming date. Why would it retain the time component when you haven't asked it to?

Comment: you are formatting to have date alone. change something like `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: hi JonK when i try that it's giving unparsable date exception.

Comment: So what format is the incoming date in? If you could provide an example that would be good.

Comment: refer this link to get current date/time. Since you said date is input by user and you have to get current time to insert into db. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java)

Comment: 2015-10-12 this is my incoming date from html page.I'm not getting time here that is my problem

Comment: read the link in my above comment to get current time. Regards

Comment: What browser are you running this in?

Comment: This is the method I use since we have to work in JRE 6 and 7. `String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().set(Calendar.HOUR, 0).set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0).set(Calendar.SECOND, 0));`

Comment: While i am executing this i get the current date and time but i need only the current time not the current date because date is to be selected by the user.