# Android Calendar format automatically

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, format

I want to set the format for the current date automatically depending on where you are. For example:
Germany: day.month.year //Today: 22.12.2015

And if you are in america:
month.day.year (Im not sure if its this format but I know its different from others)
//Today: 12.22.2015

So the output shall find the right format itself!

What Ive got so far:

```
private Calendar currentCalender = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
currentCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
currentCalender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
currentCalender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
currentCalender.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
System.out.println(currentCalendar.getTime());
```

In other forums they said I shall use SimpleFormat with yyyy-MM-dd but thats not what I want because its static and shows the same format for every country.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java

Answer (score 0):

To detect where you are, you can use the `TimeZone` class.

An example:

```
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
// This show the timezone -> tz.getDisplayName();
```

This way you will know the `TimeZone` and then the location of your device and the format you should use. Adjust the format according to the value returned by the `TimeZone`