# Scala get current-time millis with nscala-time

Tags: scala, nscala-time

I am trying to get the current time in millis doing this

```
DateTime.now.millis
```

but I get

```
Property[millisOfSecond]
```

Which is the way to get the current time in millis with nscala-time?

I want to do this, using the same library

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My bad, it was

```
DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis()
```

I leave the answer just in case is useful for someone else.

Comment: `import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}`

Comment: Since 2014 `java.time` should be used rather than `joda.time`: LocalDateTime.now() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java/5175900 has a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 38):

Alternatively, you can try:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Comment: Thank you @Sean the idea was to keep using the same library but maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: @agusgambina Can you please add all the requirements, in your question.