# I want to connect my Android bus app to the clock?

Tags: android, clock

Okay, so I am developing a bus app that gives you the next bus on your station.
On one activity I have all the buses and their times, and I just want to highlight the next bus, using the clock from the phone of the user?
Is this possible?

Comment: take the time from the clock and then match it with all the bus timing using switch case and highlight the next bus timing. Use `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current time, you don't need the device clock, you can get through simple code. Just doing `Calendar.getInstance()` gives you a new calendar object for the current time that takes timezone into account. From this object you can get the day, hour, minutes...

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175900/2707325) explains in detail how to get/use the current time

Comment: How can I , using the information from the clock, select a text to highlight?

Comment: We cannot help you more without any code on your part. Share what you've tried