# find current Date and day after tomorrow's date in java

Tags: java, date

How to find current date in java. I found a lot but every time i got same command 
Date d = new Date(); or something similar
Every such command returns a date of 1970 year.
I fail to understand, Whats the benefit of this getting a date of 1970 ?
Is there any way where i can get current time and add a second into it.
My real purpose is to convert a long value into Date and add a second in it.
5:40:12 should give me 5:40:13 after adding a second. 
Any help would be appreciated as i am fed up getting 1970 date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current date/time in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

> My real purpose is to convert a long value into Date and add a second in it. 5:40:12 should give me 5:40:13 after adding a second

The troublesome `java.util.Date` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( yourLongIntegerGoesHere )  // A moment on the timeline in UTC represented a count of nanoseconds since the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )  // Time zone for the region whose wall-clock time you want to see.
       .plusSeconds( 1 )
       .toLocalTime()                            // Extract just the time-of-day without date and without time zone.
       .toString()                               // Generate a string representing the time-of-day value in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 05:40:13

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Java.Util.Date class is deprecated, I would recommend using

```
Java.Util.Calendar instead.
```

If you're looking to add a second to Current date, try something like this:

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(); // gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale.
calendar.add(currentTime.SECOND, 1);
System.out.println(currentTime.getTime());
```

BUT, the reason why you are receiving a 1970 date when using the Date class is because that class works with milliseconds, so you must multiply the long value by 1000 in order for it to convert to a date, here's an example.

```
Date currentDate = new Date( YourLongValue * 1000);
```

Comment: It should be currentTime.add(currentTime.SECOND, 1) not calendar.