# How to show user input details back on alert dialog?

Tags: java, android

Please, i would like to show back details after the user must have input something, back on alert dialog box in Android studio. I used this code below:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_txt);
editText.getText().toString();
```

But it doesn't show on the confirmation dialog box I created.

Comment: Just calling `editText.getText().toString();` doesn't do anything. Please show some more code and format it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't set the text of your AlertDialog, but this is just an assumption because there is not enough code in your question. Calling `editText.getText().toString()` does not do anything but return a String. It does not assign it to anything. An example with an AlertDialog would be the following:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setMessage(editText.getText().toString());
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked OK button
           }
       });
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User cancelled the dialog
           }
       });
// Set other dialog properties
...

// Create the AlertDialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

I've took this example from [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) and modified it so that it includes the text of your EditText. This code should work because you not only call the `toString()` method but also assign it's return value to the AlertDialog's message property.

Comment: @Twometer...Many thanks for the help man....i have the alert dialog function all set up....the line of code i was actually looking is:                                                                                 builder.setMessage(editText.getText().toString()); . I also have another challenge, i cannot get the date and time too. I saw the get.Month() helper but it still doesn't work....Any help will be appreciated to show the date and time back to the user...

Comment: @Godymn No problem. Also, if my answer helped it would be appreciated if you accept/upvote my answer ;-).

Comment: @Godymn And, to get the current time you should take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java

Answer (score 0):

This is my entire code for the alert dialog box:

public void alertdialog(View view){

```
           mybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder cfmalt = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
                    //cfmalt.setMessage("Do you want to quit?").setCancelable(false);
                   //editText.getText().toString();
                    cfmalt.setMessage(editText.getText().toString()+"\n"+ vol_edit2.getText().toString());
                    cfmalt.setMessage(dt.getMonth())
                    //cfmalt.setMessage("Name:").setMessage(vol_edit2.getText().toString());


                    cfmalt.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    cfmalt.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });
```