# How can I get the current date and time in below format , date = "Mon, 13 Jul 2020 14:08:30 GMT"

Tags: java

need help in java code to get current date and time in below format :

`newdate = "Mon, 13 Jul 2020 14:08:30 GMT"`

After this I need to replace current date with earlier one:

`vJsonfile1.replace(earlierdate," "+ newdate);`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Consider adding some details. you can get date and timestamp using date class, break it down into string if you want another format. this is a duplicate question, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ZonedDateTime` and the RFC_1123 format to get the output you need:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT"));

System.out.println(dtf.format(zdt));
```

`Wed, 15 Jul 2020 19:07:37 GMT`

Note the 1123_DATE_TIME format doesnt play nice with North American Time zones so itll work as long as its GMT or European time zones otherwise below will suffice too:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();

System.out.println(dtf.format(zdt));
```

`Wed, 15 Jul 2020 14:13:22 CDT`

Which will output the current time with the time zone its in.

Answer (score 0):

This code does exactly what you wanted it to do.

> Output:

```
  Mi, 15 Jul 2020 08:55:21 MESZ
```

> Code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
 Date currentDate = new Date();

 System.out.println(formatter.format(currentDate));
```

Comment: I get the output as : current Date is Wed, 15 Jul 2020 03:06:27 -0400. Instead of -0400 I need to print GMT , "Wed, 15 Jul 2020 03:06:27 GMT" . Can we do this with same command by changing last digit or something like this ?

Comment: I am glad to hear that

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that formats your datetime and then changes the date portion of it:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")));
zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 15), zonedDateTime.toLocalTime(), zonedDateTime.getZone());
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")));
```