# Time stamp of date and time both in java

Tags: java, android, timestamp

How can I find the timestamp of date and time both as per the format:

```
Wed Oct 31 17:40:42 IST 2012
```

Comment: which formate you want ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010284/equivalent-of-datetime-now-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your date

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(parserSDF.format(cal.getTime()));
```

It will print as `Wed Oct 31 18:28:55 IST 2012`

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String str_date = "Wed Oct 31 18:28:55 IST 2012";

// Here is your date as string

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date); 
Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

// Here is your date as timestamp
```