# How to use now Time in android studio

Tags: android

am c# developer and in c# you can use datetime.now to get this time as example but in android studio i do not know how to do that can you help me please .
not 
I need just  hour and minute thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of C#'s DateTime.Now in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010284/equivalent-of-cs-datetime-now-in-java)

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this example to get the current date:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class GetCurrentDateTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        //get current date time with Date()
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

        //get current date time with Calendar()
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Using either `Date` or `Calendar` gives the same result in this case. But if you need to set particular dates or do date arithmetic, use a `Calendar`. `Calendar`s also handle localisation.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you are programming in Java.   Java Date provides the functionality you are looking for.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Please follow the link in my answer or type "Java Date Example" in Google.   Stack overflow (and I) disapprove of "write the code for me" requests for trivial functionality.